# route-me won't compile in xCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cloudmade, armv7, route-me

I'm trying to get route-me offline maps to compile in xCode 4.  They were fine in xCode 3.

I believe my issue is with architecture settings.  Looking at the following [post](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/issues/detail?id=138), it looks like I should change proj4 to be armv6 only and leave the main project and mapview at standard (v6 & v7).

However, I still get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMarker", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMDBMapSource", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapContents", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in XCode.
I downloaded xcode 4.0.2 and it compiles and works without any error or warnings!!

Update your xcode.

Comment: Thanks Meir.  Were you getting similar errors to me on 4.0.1?  After losing days on trying to get 4.0.2 to work and eventually backing it out, I cannot afford to rush back to 4.  When I get chance, I'll install it on our older machine and try it out first.  It certainly taught me a few lessons!

Comment: I had the exact same problem in 4,0.1, but after installing the 4.0.2 everything works well

Comment: I am now on xCode 4.02 but I still get the same errors.  I have tried adding MapView and Proj4 in as separate projects into the workspace but still no progress.  The xCode4 documentation seems to suggest it works out any dependencies, but I'm not sure it has.  If I look in Target Dependencies under the main project Target, its blank and with no option to add any.