# xCode Route-Me Compilation for Offline Maps

Tags: iphone, dictionary, xcode4, route-me

I have two related problems trying to use Route-Me and I really need some help.

It works fine in xCode 3 in the Debug and Adhoc Distribution Configurations.

**Problem 1 - App Crashes when the Map is used under the Release Configuration**

I've checked all the build settings and all the items I think should be the same are.

**Problem 2 - in xCode 4 - the Route-Me Objects are not recognised**

I'd really like to upgrade to xCode 4 but keep getting the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627255/route-me-wont-compile-in-xcode-4) and detailed below.  I am now on xCode 4.0.2 and that has not helped.  If I can do that, then hopefully I can have the main project, MapView and Proj4 as separate entities within a common workspace.  That will make settings for each configuration much more manageable and less prone to problem 1.

I have searched around and cannot see clear instructions for using route-me in xCode4, or at least none that get rid of this error.

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Chris.

**xCode 4 Error - Route-Me Objects are not recognised**

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMarker", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMDBMapSource", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapContents", referenced from: objc-class-ref in OSMapViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

Try starting from scratch and work your way back from there.

Here are my notes on how I got it working:
http://blueottersoftware.com/embedding-route-me-with-xcode-4-x/

-- Randy